# Function Not Returning result

Tags: r

I am having an issue with my code where functions won't return anything. Here is the code in question:

```
#Required libraries: rJava, rChoiceDialogs, tcltk


#Set the working directory
set_library = function(){
  library(rJava)
  library(rChoiceDialogs)
  wd = jchoose.dir()
  setwd(wd)
  return(wd)
}

#Load the csv files
load_files = function(){
  library(tcltk)
  stocks = tk_choose.files()
  print(length(stocks))
  return(stocks)
}

set_library()
load_files()
print(length(stocks))
```

The function will print the length in the `load_files` function but not at the end.

Comment: the issue lies in scope of variables , to resolve it you can : _1 :_ store result of functions in variable like `stocks1 <- load_files()` and then try `print(length(stocks1))` or _2 :_ use `<<-` for assignment to a global environment as `stocks <<- tk_.......`

Comment: `stocks` is defined inside the `load_files` function, which is a local object. Hence it cannot be accessed outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save `stocks` in the parent scope:

```
# Required libraries: rJava, rChoiceDialogs, tcltk

# Set the working directory
set_library = function() {
  library(rJava)
  library(rChoiceDialogs)
  wd = jchoose.dir()
  setwd(wd)
  return(wd)
}

# Load the csv files
load_files = function() {
  library(tcltk)
  stocks = tk_choose.files()
  # print(length(stocks))
  return(stocks)
}

set_library()
stocks <- load_files()
print(length(stocks))
```